# Prove that $L_A(X)=AX-XA$ is symmetric if and only if $A$ is symmetric.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

> Define for a fixed $A \in \mathbb{M}^{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ the
>   mapping:
>
> $$L_A : \mathbb{M}^{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{M}^{2 \times
> 2}(\mathbb{R}) : X \mapsto AX-XA. $$
>
> Define on $\mathbb{M}^{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ the dotproduct $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ as follows:
>   $ \langle X, Y \rangle = [X]_{\xi}^t [Y]_{\xi}$.
>
> Here is $[\cdot ]_\xi$ the coordinate map
>   that belongs to the standard basis
>
> $$\xi = \{ E_1 = {\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}},
> E_2={\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}},
> E_3={\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}},
> E_4={\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}} \}$$ of
>   $\mathbb{M}^{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})$.
>
> Write $M_A$ for the matrix such
>   that for all $X \in \mathbb{M}^{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ it satisfies
>   $[L_A (X)]_\xi=M_A [X]_\xi$.
>
> Prove that $L_A$ is symmetric if and only if $A$ is symmetric.

In a previous exercise I had to determine all the matrices $M_{E_1}, M_{E_2}, M_{E_3}, M_{E_4}$. And this is the result:

$M_{E_1} = {\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}},~M_{E_2}={\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}}, ~M_{E_3}={\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}}, \\M_{E_4}={\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}}$

How am I to use this to prove the given problem? I already showed that $L_A$ is symmetric if and only if $M_A$ is symmetric, meaning $\langle L_A(X), Y \rangle = \langle X, L_A(Y) \rangle$ if and only if $M_A = M_A^t$.

I am at a loss. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This makes little sense. Part one, why does your definition of the inner product has no letter $Y$ in the right hand side? Second, what do you mean by symmetric for your operator? And, mostly, where did you get this?

Comment: I noticed a few mistakes. What I mean by symmetric is that $\langle L_A (X), Y \rangle = \langle X, L_A (Y) \rangle$ for all $X \in \mathbb{M}^{2 \times 2} (\mathbb{R})$. This is one of my teacher's questions to refresh some of our linear algebra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A=\pmatrix{a&b\\ c&d}$. Then $M_A=aM_{E_1}+cM_{E_2}+bM_{E_3}+dM_{E_4}$. Here are some entries of $M_A$:
$$
M_A=\pmatrix{
0  &b   &-c &0\\
c  &d-a &0  &-c\\
-b &0   &\ast &\ast\\
0  &-b  &\ast &\ast}.\tag{1}
$$
And I will leave the rest to you. Now, the given inner product $\langle X,Y\rangle$ is the usual dot product of $[X]_{\xi}$ and $[Y]_{\xi}$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$. Therefore, $L_A$ is symmetric w.r.t. $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ if and only if $M_A$ is a symmetric matrix. More specifically,
\begin{align*}
L_A \text{ is symmetric }
&\Leftrightarrow \langle L_A(X),Y\rangle=\langle X,L_A(Y)\rangle \text{ for all } X,Y\in M^{2\times2}(\mathbb{R})\\
&\Leftrightarrow [X]_{\xi}^tM_A^t [Y]_{\xi}=[X]_{\xi}^t M_A[Y]_{\xi} \text{ for all } X,Y\in M^{2\times2}(\mathbb{R})\\
&\Leftrightarrow u^tM_A^tv=u^t M_Av \text{ for all } u,v\in \mathbb{R}^4\\
&\Leftrightarrow M_A^t=M_A.
\end{align*}

From $(1)$, we see that for $M_A$ to be symmetric, a necessary condition is $b=c$. If you could determine the unspecified entries of $M_A$ correctly (note that your $M_{E_3}$ is wrong; there's perhaps a typo), you will see that $b=c$ is also a sufficient condition. Hence the result.

Comment: Thanks for doing the way the person who wrote the exercise had in mind, +1.

Answer (score 5):

**Note:** I am sorry this is a little far from your notations. But lots of people would define this inner product as $\mbox{Tr}(X^*Y)$. This idea of using the trace to create bilinear objects is frequent and natural (see the [Killing form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_form), to mention one famous example). Last but not least, observe that **the argument below applies to $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and even $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ for any $n$.** This is my main motivation for doing it the following way. If you are only interested in the $2\times 2$ case, then you should keep your notations and do like @user1551 did.

Observe that the inner product you are given on the matrices has a nice and tractable [matrix trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29) expression:

> $$
> (X,Y)=\mbox{Tr}(X^*Y)
> $$

where $X^*$ denotes the adjoint of $X$, i.e. the transpose in the real case.

Now, using the commutativity of the trace $\mbox{Tr}(MN)=\mbox{Tr}(NM)$, straightforward computations show that
$$
(L_A(X),Y)=\mbox{Tr}(A^*(YX^*-X^*Y))
$$
while
$$
(X,L_A(Y))=\mbox{Tr}(A(YX^*-X^*Y)).
$$

**Easy direction:** it follows at once that if $A=A^*$, then $(L_A(X),Y)=(X,L_A(Y))$ for every $X,Y$. Hence $L_A=L_A^*$, i.e. $L_A$ is symmetric.

**Conversely:** assume that $L_A=L_A^*$. Then the matrix $B=A-A^*$ satisfies $$\mbox{Tr}(B(YX^*-X^*Y))=\mbox{Tr}((BY-YB)X^*) =0$$ for every $X,Y$.
First, this implies, with $X=BY-YB$, 
$$
\|BY-YB\|^2=\mbox{Tr}((BY-YB)^*(BY-YB))=\mbox{Tr}((BY-YB)(BY-YB)^*) =0.
$$
Where the norm is the one induced by your inner product. It follows that $BY-YB=0$ for every $Y$, i.e. $B$ commutes with every other matrix. It is well-know that the only such matrices are the scalar matrices (nice exercise, just compute the products with matrices of the canonical basis $E_{ij}$). So $B=A-A^*=\lambda I_2$. But taking the trace of the latter, we find $2\lambda=\mbox{Tr}(A)-\mbox{Tr}(A^*)=0$. Finally, $B=A-A^*=0$, so $A=A^*$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

"Another" way is the following:

Show that $\langle L_{E_2}(X),Y\rangle=\langle X,L_{E_3}(Y)\rangle$ and that $\langle L_{E_3}(X),Y\rangle=\langle X,L_{E_2}(Y)\rangle$ (actually these two are equivalent).
Therefore for $A=\begin{pmatrix} a_1&a_3\\a_2&a_4\end{pmatrix}$ we have (note that $M_{E_1},M_{E_4}$ are symmetric) 
$$
\langle L_A(X),Y\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^4a_i\langle L_{E_i}(X),Y\rangle=\\
a_1\langle X,L_{E_1}(Y)\rangle+a_2\langle X,L_{E_3}(Y)\rangle+a_3\langle X,L_{E_2}(Y)\rangle+a_4\langle X,L_{E_4}(Y)\rangle=\\
\langle X,L_{A^t}(Y)\rangle.
$$
It follows that $L_A$ is symmetric $\iff \langle X,L_{A}(Y)\rangle=\langle X,L_{A^t}(Y)\rangle, \ \forall X,Y\in M^{2\times2}(\mathbb R)\ldots$